# How should I define the callbacks with $http when using Typescript?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

My $http call looks like this and I would like to know the most flexible way to handle all of the parameters that are returned in the .success and .error?

```
this.$http({ url: "/api/x, method: "GET" })
   .success((??) : void => {

   })
   .error((??) : void => {

   })
```

The Angular documentation tells me the following are returned:

```
data – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
status – {number} – HTTP status code of the response.
headers – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.
config – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
statusText – {string} – HTTP status text of the response.
```

angular.d.ts shows me:

```
interface IHttpPromiseCallback<T> {
        (data: T, status: number, headers: (headerName: string) => string, config: IRequestConfig): void;
    }

    interface IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<T> {
        data?: T;
        status?: number;
        headers?: (headerName: string) => string;
        config?: IRequestConfig;
        statusText?: string;
    }
```

But I am still confused. Has anyone used the two interfaces above to define the callbacks and how did they do it?

Ideally I would like to have something like this:

```
 .success((data: any, status: number, headers: (headerName: string) => string, config: any) : void => {
```

But using the interfaces.

Can anyone tell me if I am on the right track and if I could use the interfaces rather than having to specify the :any :number etc after the parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's and example for the GET:

```
  private getInternal<T>(url) {
        var deferred = this.$q.defer();

        this.$http({ url: url, method: "GET" })
            .success((data: T, status: number, headers: (headerName: string) => string, config: ng.IRequestConfig): void => {
                if (status == 200 && headers('location') == null && config.timeout > 200) {
                    //do something with data
                }

                return deferred.resolve(data);
            })
            .error((data: T, status: number, headers: (headerName: string) => string, config: ng.IRequestConfig): void => {
                if (status == 500 && headers('myAuth') != null && config.method == 'GET') {
                    // write to log
                }

                return deferred.reject(data);
            });
    }
```

Now let's say you have a service and you know your getting a specific object:

```
this.getInternal<mySpecObject>('service/abc').then(res => doSomethingWithData(res));
```

Comment: Where does 'req' in 'var deferred in req.deferred' come from?

Comment: @TorbenRahbekKoch, it has to be $q:ng.IQService (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Comment: I suppose getInternal should also return an object. angular.IDeffered<T> or angular.IPromise ? then you call the .then

Answer (score 6):

I realize this is a very old post, but I don't think the answers here are adequate (even for way-back-when, when this question was asked).

status is always going to be a number, so don't worry about that parameter.

You are likely seeking a way to handle the response in a strongly typed way.

The first property, data, is probably the main one you're concerned with. In your time, that .success/.error arg would be defined like:

```
this.$http({ url: "/api/x, method: "GET" })
   .success((response: IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<IMyInterface>) : void => {
        console.log("Hello "+ response.data.firstName);
   })
   .error((response: IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<IMyInterface>) : void => {

   })
```

Here in the future, .success and .error are deprecated and $http should be handled more like a standard promise:

```
this.$http({ url: "/api/x, method: "GET" })
    .then((response: IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<IMyInterface>) => {
        console.log("Hello "+ response.data.firstName);
    }, (response: IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<IMyInterface>) => {
        console.log("Boo, error code "+ response.status);
    });
```

And those are both assuming you have the data coming from your web service that fits the following:

```
export interface IMyInterface {
    firstName: string
}
```

**UPDATE 12/4/2017**

Whoa, it's me again from even further in the future!  Now `IHttpPromiseCallbackArg` is deprecated.  Things here in the future sure are complicated.  How I long for simpler times.

(J/K it's actually easier now.)

Instead of `IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<>`, use: `IHttpResponse<>`.  It appears the interface signature is mostly (completely?) the same and is a drop-in replacement.

```
this.$http({ url: "/api/x, method: "GET" })
    .then((response: IHttpResponse<IMyInterface>) => {
        console.log("Hello "+ response.data.firstName);
    }, (response: IHttpResponse<IMyInterface>) => {
        console.log("Boo, error code "+ response.status);
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

here is what i did

```
module portal.services {


export class apiService {


    public getData<T>(url?:string): ng.IPromise<T> {

        var def = this.$q.defer();
        this.$http.get(this.config.apiBaseUrl + url).then((successResponse) => {

            if(successResponse)
                def.resolve(successResponse.data);
            else
                def.reject('server error');

        }, (errorRes) => {

            def.reject(errorRes.statusText);
        });

        return def.promise;
    }

    public postData<T>(formData: any, url?:string,contentType?:string): ng.IPromise<T>{

        var def = this.$q.defer();

        this.$http({
            url: this.config.apiBaseUrl + url,
            method: 'POST',
            data:formData,
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type':contentType || 'application/json'
            }
        }).then((successResponse)=>{
            def.resolve(successResponse.data);
        },(errorRes)=>{
            def.reject(errorRes);
        });

        return def.promise;

    }

    static $inject = ['$q','$http', 'config'];

    constructor(public $q:ng.IQService,public $http:ng.IHttpService, public config:interfaces.IPortalConfig) {


    }

}
```

}

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to use getData in a controller?